# Finding sum of the infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> > Find the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left ( \frac {\log (\log x)} {n!} \right )^n.$$

How do I proceed? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should start from $n=2$ to avoid problems.

Comment: @tommy1996q Why? Note that the logarithm only depends on $x$, not on $n$.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @MisterRiemann.

Comment: Ops, yeah you are both right

Comment: Yeah what I have written is perfectly fine. Otherwise the sum would be $e^{\log (\log x)} = \log x$. Which is obvious.

Comment: May I ask: Why is this sum of interest?

Comment: It is a question of the entrance examination of IIT-JEE in India.

Comment: Don't be impressed by the expression $\log(\log x)$, replace it by $t$.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with $\log x$ . Define $f(x):=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{n!}\right)^n$ , for which no closed form is known, then the result is $f(\log\log x)$ . But that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form expression to this series. The general term is extremely quickly decreasing. With $t=\log(\log(x))$,

$$1+t+\frac{t^2}4+\frac{t^3}{216}+\frac{t^4}{331776}+\frac{t^5}{24883200000}+\cdots$$

Comment: Do you have an argument that there is no closed form expression?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: firm conviction. (Note that Alpha has nothing to say about it.) I am also pretty sure that the question was wrongly reproduced.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: other argument is that this function is so close to a polynomial, that it would take the usual functions terrible contortions to match it.

Comment: I agree that it looks very probably true, but I had hoped that "so close to a polynomial" or something like it corresponded to a known rigorous criterion.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: so had I. If one could find a differential equation, then one could use the Liouville theorem.

Comment: But all the advanced things in maths are not all known to the students who are preparing for IIT-JEE. They are actually 12th standard.

Comment: If no further computational approximation to the sum of the above series can be made we have to wait for a second Ramanujan or the question makers who would probably tackle it.